# On a loop: fgets keeps reading only one line that keeps getting used in the following loop

Tags: php, html

My goal from my code (using only HTML and PHP) is to provide a page for choosing the type of question (checkbox...) with the number of inputs and display the result in a different page by reading the 3 files that has been already saved in 3 main files (file for questions, file for number of inputs, file for options content), my idea is almost.

Here's my code from the displaying page :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
form du reponse
</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
//3 files
$k=fopen("choix multiples.txt","a+");//questions
$nn=fopen("nombre.txt","a+");//number of inputs
$no=fopen("les_options_multiples.txt","a+");//options content
//from here it only reads the first line of $nn and it keeps using it on the last loop 
for($lol=fgets($nn);!feof($nn);$lol=fgets($nn))
{
for($questioncm=fgets($k);!feof($k);$questioncm=fgets($k))
{
echo "$questioncm :<br/>";
for($x=1;$x<=$lol;$x++)
{
echo fgets($no);
?> 
<form action="" method="POST">
<div>
<input name="haha" type="radio"  value="hahaha">
</div>
<?php
}
?>
</form>
<?php
}
}
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure that `"a+"` is the correct mode for the files?

Comment: It probably makes more sense to use `while()` instead of `for()` when using `fgets()`. [The manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) has a good example.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I already use other mods of writing in files as well as changing for to while , nothing happened , it gives the same result

Comment: The weird thing is the code was working more than fine until  server began to crash , Idk if the problem is from fgets buffering or for loop .(ps: I use usbwebserver as a server host ) . if using DB will solve the problem plz inform me asap